scrape a website which has the same url for multiple pages? with the page jump being an ajax request
I've been at this for days, I'm trying to scrape this website: "https://careers.ispor.org/jobseeker/search/results/".
I've got everything covered, from the script that will extract the information in every job page to the script that counts how many pages are there, but in order to get the individual links of every job posting, I need to loop through the pages containing 25 listings each, but THAT is the problem:

it's all under the same URL
forget about Selenium, it gets detected and blocked after 2 tries
the data loads with javascript so the regular requests method doesn't work,
the only working method I found is by using Zenrows' free trial to make the request

Here's my code so far, I got the first page's data successfully using this:
from zenrows import ZenRowsClient

client = ZenRowsClient("the_api_key_i_got_from_the_trial_account")
url = "https://careers.ispor.org/jobseeker/search/results"
params = {"js_render":"true","premium_proxy":"true"}

response = client.get(url, params=params)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')

after that I've been trying to replicate the ajax request that I inspected when I clicked on the "next page" button, but the result I keep getting only mimics having gone to the next page while the job postings on the returned result are of the first page:
data = {
    'page': '2',
    'pos_flt': '0',
    'location_autocomplete': 'true',
    'radius': '320',
    'ajaxRequest': '1',
    'user_latlong': 'lat=33.874698638916$long=10.102299690247',
    "js_render": "true",
    "premium_proxy": "true"
}
cookies = {
    'AWSALB': "e6+c5w9IR/N4+ERov3onMB85zlZbl+mughxR4zfjLRLMoq9SJwBHTesVwdSAoTLuK88spU0tbqTVZ8jI7NGHLxMo/7Q+DefZBboxMZDGRMLBY60+HRQaBnKOYDhJ",
    'AWSALBCORS': "e6+c5w9IR/N4+ERov3onMB85zlZbl+mughxR4zfjLRLMoq9SJwBHTesVwdSAoTLuK88spU0tbqTVZ8jI7NGHLxMo/7Q+DefZBboxMZDGRMLBY60+HRQaBnKOYDhJ",
    'JTSUBREF': "careers.ispor.org",
    'datadome': "pn970laC_lalBETD5NWHB~pVKYYLrP2fg9_1JlfW1POc~Ny5Usr37BfuNP1UiAl3kCxoOA7z0Pvlwo69rK5WBre5T9znj0U3p55vC_mMGn1w56eqcSU1eWpla3DYLyJb"
}
headers = {
    'authority': 'careers.ispor.org',
    'method': 'GET',
    'path': '/c/@search_results/controller/includes/search_jobs.cfm?page=2&pos_flt=0&location_autocomplete=true&radius=320&ajaxRequest=1&user_latlong=lat%3D33.874698638916%24long%3D10.102299690247',
    'scheme': 'https'
}
response = client.get(url, params=params, headers=headers, cookies=cookies, data=data)
soup2 = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')


You don't need Zenrows for this, you can simply replicate the ajax requests. Here's a quick example:
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json

def get_jobs_list(page_number):
    params = {
        'page': page_number,
        'pos_flt': 0,
        'location_autocomplete': True,
        'radius': 320,
        'ajaxRequest': 1
    }

    url = 'https://careers.ispor.org/c/@search_results/controller/includes/search_jobs.cfm'
    response = requests.get(url, params=params, headers=headers)
    data = response.json()

    soup = BeautifulSoup(data['search_results'], 'html.parser')
    divs = soup.select('div.job-result-tiles > div[role=button]:not(.candidate-products-promotion-tile)')

    names = ['job_id', 'job_Position', 'job_company', 'job_source', 'job_Location']
    jobs = [{ n: d.select_one(f'input[name="{n}"]').get('value') for n in names} for d in divs]

    return jobs


def get_job_details(job_id, job_source=None):
    params = {
        'job_id': job_id,
        'job_source': job_source,
        'site_id': 23051,
        'ajaxRequest': 1,
    }

    url = 'https://careers.ispor.org/c/@search_results/controller/includes/search_job.cfm'
    response = requests.get(url, params=params, headers=headers)
    data = response.json()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(data['job_view'], 'html.parser')

    desc = soup.select_one('div.job-description-parent-container')
    apply_json =  json.loads(soup.select_one('input#applyButtonJson').get('value'))

    details = {
        'description': desc.get_text(separator='\n').strip(),
        'apply_link': apply_json['linkAttr']['href'] if apply_json['link'] else apply_json['modalAttr']['href_email']
    }

    return details


headers = {
    'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/128.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
}


jobs = get_jobs_list(page_number=3)
print(jobs)

# get the datails of a job:
# job_id, job_source = jobs[0]['job_id'], jobs[0]['job_source']
# details = get_job_details(job_id, job_source)
# print(details)


focusing on directly replicating the AJAX requests made by the website in order to fetch the data needed instead of obsessing over loading the entire page correctly is actually really smart, Thank you!!

Here you will need to use Paid proxies
with parameters similar to the following
'render_js': 'false',
'residential': 'true'

And with BeautifulSoup get all the href of the 25 links and then for each link scrape the job posting, I tested this with few examples, and it gets the href like in here, you will need to add the base link to those and then scrape each result again.
Hope this helps
#
/job/postdoctoral-fellow-us-infectious-disease-epidemiology/75118162/
#
/job/assistant-professor-center-for-value-based-care-research/75118214/
#
/job/oncology-clinical-pharmacist/74728623/
#
/job/director-institutional-outreach-and-collaboration/73729688/
#
/job/director-cler-site-visit-operations/73729629/
#
/job/staff-associate-ii/75118241/
#
/job/dircorporate-medical-records/74866586/
#


my problem was never about getting the job links, i mentioned that i have that figured out already, my problem is getting the listings that exist on the next pages, what you provided now is from page 1
